# php environment variable is not working

Tags: php, windows

I've followed tutorials and answer here on Stackoverflow, but I still can't access php.exe from command line.

All I get is:

`php is not recognized as an internal or external command...`

[image]

How can I make php.exe accessible from anywhere in the command line?

What else can I try to execute PHP from command line?

Comment: Did you reinitialize the `cmd` after making changes to path? Also do `echo %PATH%` in cmd, you see php executable path you have just added.

Comment: @RahilWazir That's the nicest way I have heard anyone ask "Have you tried turning it off... and on again?" mate. Gold :)

Comment: Yes :) I've rebooted my computer - twice. Once when I had `\php.exe` and once when I had `\php`

Comment: @Steven You don't need to reboot the computer :). You need to remove the `php` from `php5.4.12/php` if `php.exe` lives in `php5.4.12/` directory root.

Comment: @RahilWazir Ah, removing `php` worked. Want to put that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Path should be

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12
```

without **php** at end